# individual - location-type work address

Tags: contacts, addresses, address-labels, location-type

examples

- Individual 1: Thomas Hess, work address bank of switzerland, 8050
  Zürich
- Individual 2: Steven Müller, work address bank of switzerland,
  8010 Zürich

So I have 10 individuals of this kind and each works in another office of this bank.

It is confusing to add 10 new organisation only to have a work address. And to
add a Work address I need a field for the companie's name but there are only supplemental 1 and 2 field.

How can I add an work address?

Answer (score 2):

Let me think a bit on how I would tackle this. I suppose that if I was only interested in the work addresses of Steven and Thomas I would simply add the work address on the Individual contact level. If I am however interested in the employer/employee relationship as well I can see no other option than having each branch as an Organisation. I would probably add a contact_sub_type for this, something like 'local organization' with a relationship 'Local Branch of' with the main office so I have the whole pattern clear.

Comment: Reading again Oliver's question, chances are that the Steven and Thomas are actually employees of the (main) organisation, not from the local branch, it might be an issue to have a more logical but less legally correct relationship. This being said, the right way IMO to handle the relationships and deal with branches indeed.

Comment: We agree once again :-)

Answer (score 0):

So you can create a single organisation (bank of switzerland, and put the address there), add a relationship between each of your individuals and the organisation AND check "share address" on each individual to automatically use the address of the organisation.

So if the bank of Switzerland decides to move its headquarters to the cayman island for fiscal optimisation, you're covered, Thomas and Steven will automatically have their addresses updated ;)

X+

Comment: Not if they work in different branches :-)

Comment: thx. I dont want to use the "share address" because than I have to open 10 new organisations (because the bank of switzerland exists in 
8050 Zürich
8010 Zürich etc.

I want to enter the work address manually but there is no field for the name of the organisation. How do I enter the name of the organisation?

or does exist an solution with the share address option?

Comment: you could use the complementary address 1 line for the name of the organization?

Comment: i don't want to establish a relation between the individuel and the organisation because it is not needed and to complicated because I have to register 10 different addresses from the same organisation (different town, departement etc.)

but i want to have a work address of the contact. how can i register this?